# axios get request for real-time data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

For simplicity assume that I have entity user and in my frontend side (react) I am making an Axios get request to get all users to display them.

In the `componentDidMount` I am doing a get request `const res = axios.get(myurl)` then map the `res` to be displayed.

However, if a new user is entered in the database I have to refresh the page to see the update.

Here is my question, how to make the get request to be like running or something like this so if any changes happens in the database it reflects the get request.

Comment: look into websockets and pushing data based on an event (ex: adding a user)
Right now, it is pull based (when the page loads, you pull all users).

Comment: if you do axios get request in componentDidUpdate and update the state in it. when the state will change the component will re-render and you don't have to refresh the page. but i don't think this is write way but you can try. also you have to use redux for that else it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a real-time updates, and we have multiple practices for such a case.

Before reading the answer, you need to know that this case is about the real-time updates concept and not a problem with a line of code solution. You need to implement real-time system in your app to achieve what you want.

### 1st Practice

- Is to use a real-time library like Socket.io, so that you can listen to the events you want.
  You can find [here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/creating-a-real-time-chat-app-with-react-socket-io-with-e2e-encryption/) an example for Node.JS with React.JS

### 2nd Practice

- Is to use a database that provides real-time updates like Firebase. [Here](https://grotoned.medium.com/tutorial-using-firebase-as-a-realtime-database-with-react-2a3a24c1df91) you can find an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the useEffect in react

```js
import React,{useEffect}from 'react'

function getAllUsers(){
    //your code here...
}

useEffect(()=>{
        getAllUsers();

    })
```

Comment: `{"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module","filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js","lineno": 12,"colno": 9}` You're using `import` in a browser environment. Change it to CommonJS.